# How to verify TPM-generated signatures with OpenSSL?

Tags: digital-signature, tpm, tss, remote-attestation, nvram

I'm working with a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) and need to generate a Signing Key (SK) that can be proven to reside within the same TPM as the Attestation Identity Key (AIK). My goal is to enable a server, which does not have a TPM, to verify that the SK originated from my TPM using OpenSSL.
Here's what I have accomplished so far:

```
sudo tpm2_createek -c ek.ctx -G rsa -u ek.pub -P 123
sudo tpm2_createak -C ek.ctx -c ak.ctx -G rsa -g sha256 -s rsassa -u ak.pub -n ak.name -P 123
sudo tpm2_load -C ek.ctx -u ak.pub -r ak.priv -n ak.name -c ak.ctx
sudo tpm2_createprimary -C o -c primary.ctx -G rsa -P 123
sudo tpm2_create -C primary.ctx -G rsa -u sk.pub -r sk.priv -a "fixedtpm|fixedparent|sensitivedataorigin|userwithauth"
sudo tpm2_load -C primary.ctx -u sk.pub -r sk.priv -n sk.name -c sk.ctx
sudo tpm2_certify -C ak.ctx -c sk.ctx -g sha256 -o certify.signature -f plain
```

After generating the signature, I attempted to verify it using OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify ak.pub -signature certify.signature sk.pub
Verification Failure
```

The certify.signature file is a binary file and I suspect it contains more than just the signature (likely it includes TPM structures). How can I extract just the raw signature from this binary file in a format that OpenSSL can verify?

Any help on how to correctly verify the TPM-generated signature using OpenSSL would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I currently cannot reproduce your problem, but the following should help. Essentially `tpm2_readpublic` can give you a PEM-formatted key, which seems to be what you need, here.

From the [tpm2-tools integration tests](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/4998ecfea817cd0efdd47bdf11a02dedab51c723/test/integration/tests/certify.sh#L42):

```bash
tpm2 createprimary -Q -C e -g sha256 -G rsa -c primary.ctx -p signedpass

tpm2 create -Q -g sha256 -G rsa:rsassa -u certify.pub -r certify.priv \
    -C primary.ctx -P signedpass -p certifypass

tpm2 load -Q -C primary.ctx -P signedpass -u certify.pub -r certify.priv \
    -n certify.name -c certify.ctx

tpm2 certify \
    -c primary.ctx -P signedpass \
    -C certify.ctx -p certifypass \
    -g sha256 -o attest.out -f plain -s sig.out

# Verify the signatures with openssl
tpm2 readpublic -Q -c certify.ctx -f pem -o certify.pem
openssl dgst -verify certify.pem -keyform pem -sha256 \
    -signature sig.out attest.out
```

Comment: Is there any way I can certify this with an AIK, and then verify it on the server side by using the ak.pub? I've tried, but it's not working.